# Pointers in c change static int value

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers, data-structures

I tried to write mergeSort algorithm in C using pointers (I am new to pointers). I used a `static int n` (n = number of elements) and `v` (the array of elements). After mergeSort algorithm, `n` value is modified with a random number every time. What did I do wrong?

Here I read the input

```
int *v = malloc(NMAX * sizeof(int));
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);

int i;
for (i = 0; i <  n; ++i) {
    scanf("%d", &v[i]);
}
```

Here is the mergeSort algorithm:

```
void mergeSort(int st, int dr, int *v) {
    if (st < dr) {
        int mij = (st + dr) / 2;
        mergeSort(st, mij, &v);
        mergeSort(mij + 1, dr, &v);
        mergeElements(st, dr, &v);
    }
}

void mergeElements(int st, int dr, int *v) {
    int *auxArray = malloc((dr - st + 3) * sizeof(int));
    int pos = 0;
    int sPos = st;
    int mij = (st + dr) / 2;
    int dPos = mij + 1;

    for (pos = 0; pos < (dr - st + 1); ++pos) {
        if (dPos == dr + 1) {
            auxArray[pos] = v[sPos];
            sPos++;
        } else if (sPos == mij + 1) {
            auxArray[pos] = v[dPos];
            dPos++;
        } else {
            if (v[sPos] < v[dPos]) {
                auxArray[pos] = v[sPos];
                sPos++;
            } else {
                auxArray[pos] = v[dPos];
                dPos++;
            }
        }
    }
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < pos; ++i) {
        v[st + i] = auxArray[i];
    }
    free(auxArray);
}
```

And here is where I get error (in `main`):

```
mergeSort(0, n - 1, &v);

printf("%d", n);
```

I get `n` to be `1998609340` instead of `6`.

Edit: Here is where I print the elements:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    printf("%d ", v[i]);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be passing `&v` in your internal calls to `mergeSort` and `mergeElement`. You don't want the pointer to the pointer. You just want to keep passing `v`, the pointer.

Comment: @lurker Oh yes, now it works. But when I try to print the elements I am getting error ( the console don't finish ). Do you know why ?

Comment: This `int *v = malloc( NMAX * sizeof(int) );` should be after scanning the `n` value from user. And it should be `int *v = malloc(n * sizeof(*v) );`

Comment: your compiler should report diagnostics messages for the `&v` thing - are sure you know where/how to read them?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala If I stop using &v into the mergeSort recursion, n remains the same, but I can't print elements. Do you know why ?

Comment: Then please provide a proper [mcve] - a program that compiles and runs and demonstrates the problem.

Comment: This should not compile. What kind of compiler are you using? Are you getting any compiler warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

&v shouldn't be passed in your calls to mergeSort and mergeElement.
&v is actually of type int** **while your function prototype supports int ***.
(there must had been a warning while compiling your code)

Hey here's the code after debugging (just changed &v back to v while calling mergeSort & mergeElements)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define NMAX 1000
void mergeElements(int st, int dr, int *v);

void mergeSort(int st, int dr, int *v) {
    if (st < dr) {
        int mij =  ( st + dr ) / 2;
        mergeSort(st, mij, v);
        mergeSort(mij + 1, dr, v);
        mergeElements(st, dr, v);
    }
}

void mergeElements(int st, int dr, int *v) {

    int *auxArray = malloc( (dr - st + 3) * sizeof(int) );

    int pos = 0;
    int sPos = st;
    int mij = ( st + dr ) / 2;
    int dPos = mij + 1;

    for (pos = 0; pos < (dr - st + 1); ++pos) {
        if (dPos == dr + 1) {
            auxArray[pos] = v[sPos];
            sPos ++;
        } else if (sPos == mij + 1) {
            auxArray[pos] = v[dPos];
            dPos ++;
        } else {
            if (v[sPos] < v[dPos] ) {
                auxArray[pos] = v[sPos];
                sPos ++;
            } else {
                auxArray[pos] = v[dPos];
                dPos ++;
            }
        }
    }
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < pos; ++i) {
        v[st + i] = auxArray[i];
    }

    free(auxArray);

}

int main()
{
    int *v = malloc( NMAX * sizeof(int) );
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <  n; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", &v[i]);
    }
    mergeSort(0,n-1,v);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",v[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: A code dump is not a good answer. To be useful it needs an explanation of the problem(s) found and how they were fixed.

Comment: Thanks to guide me. I'll surely take care of this in all of my answers in the future